# Import data from Word 2003 (Doc) file to Access?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-access, import

Is there any way to import data from  a table in Word 2003 (Doc) file to Access 2010?I tried External Data menu in Access 2010 but it has not an option for importing from Doc file.

Really I did not create Doc files.I have in about 50 Doc files and I have to import their data to the Access DB.Thank you.

Edit:

All data in files have the same structure and I have to add them in to one table in Access.Also I had not use macros yet.

Comment: More information is needed in order for anyone to be able to really help you. What have you already tried? Is there only one table per document? Is all the data from the 50 documents being combined into the same table? Are you capable of adding code for a macro?

Comment: @CharlieRB I added more details to the question.Please see it again.Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4465212/1141581) article. This can help you get the data from Word to Excel. Once you get it to Excel, you can use an import wizard to put the data into the Access table. I've not found anything to import directly from Word to Access.

Comment: @CharlieRB OK,please add your reply as answer,so I can Accept it as true answer.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4465212/1141581). This can help you get the data from Word to Excel. Once you get it to Excel, you can use an import wizard to put the data into the Access table. I've not found anything to import directly from Word to Access.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your tables in Word are quite simple (no merged cells etc.). Then for each table,

1. Remove any heading rows that you don't want . You may also need to
   select repeating headers and make them non-repeating.
2. If necessary,add a heading row containing the column names you want
   in Access.
3. Select the entire table using the selection box above the top left
   cell of the table, and ctrl-C to the clipboard.
4. In Access, create a new table. Here, I see the new, empty table
   displayed in data sheet view with an ID column, and a cell selected
   in a column titled "click to add".
5. Ctrl-V to paste the data.

The table header row should be used to create the Access column names. You can then do everything else you need using, e.g. Access table design, queries etc

Comment: Oh no,copy-paste need long time.I mentioned before that I have in about 50 files and I search in about a way with minimum time.

Comment: Sure, it would take a long time, but unless someone has the exact utility you need and it works straight away, it will probably be quicker doing 50 by hand. If you need to do this repeatedly, that's a different story and you should say that in the question.